# Tags of html not working in php

Tags: php, html

Hi i have a small line of code where i got data from mysql database and tried to display that data using html tag.I am able to display the chart but The real problem is if i write the html tag, to display the data inside the chart then tags are not working and even tags areg getting printed in side the chart with my data

If i use echo to write html code, then i am getting this kind of error. 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

> Error : **syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO).**

Please go through the code , i dont know where i had done the mistake.

```
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $temp = array();
        $temp[] = array('v' =>  $row['Email'],'f' =>  "<p>{$row['First_Name']}</p><p>{$row['Email']}</p><img src = {$row['imageurl']} width='100px' height='100px'></img>");
        $temp[] = array('v' => $row['Name'],'f' =>  "{$row['Name'] }{$row['Name']}");
        $table['rows'][] = array('c' => $temp);
    }
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);




        <script type="text/javascript">

            function drawVisualization() {
                   var jtable = <?php echo $jsonTable; ?>
                // Create and populate the data table.
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);

                // Create and draw the visualization.
               var table = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
                table.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
     }
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
            google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['orgchart']});
            google.visualization.events.trigger(table,'select', function() {
 alert('selected');
});
             // Add our over/out handlers.


        </script>
```

\

Comment: Post that echo part too. Where you were getting this errro

Comment: there is no `echo` in this code. So what you have provided is probably not where your issue is.

Comment: I suspect that you are escaping the html tags in your html. please post your html code too.

Comment: there is no error in this code. please post code prior to this or below. Post whole error message which will be helpful.

Comment: If i put and echo and write html then i am getting error otherwise, even the html tags are printing in the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had added  `table.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});`

I made a mistake by not writing allowHtml, because of this reason my html tags were not working

Thanks,
Sai Nishank